# Highcharts bar chart how can add series events?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

see the code in jsFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/ghRF9/

```
            series: [{
            name: 'Tokyo',
            data: {
                y : [49.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4],
                events : {
                    click : function(){
                        alert(1);
                    }
                }
            }

        }....the click not work , and not bar in the chart...pls someone help..
```

line on 52 ,I wanna add click listener in the tokyo click event,how can work

Comment: Your code is working except for Tokyo as there is no bar appearing for Tokyo. If you add alert event for Newyork you can see the alert is working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like:

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Monthly Average Rainfall'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: [
                'Jan',
                'Feb',
                'Mar',
                'Apr',
                'May',
                'Jun',
                'Jul',
                'Aug',
                'Sep',
                'Oct',
                'Nov',
                'Dec'
            ]
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'Rainfall (mm)'
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><table>',
            pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}: </td>' +
                '<td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y:.1f} mm</b></td></tr>',
            footerFormat: '</table>',
            shared: true,
            useHTML: true
        },
        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                pointPadding: 0.2,
                borderWidth: 0
            },
            series: {
                events : {
                    click : function(){
                        if(this.name == "Tokio") {
                                /* do something here */
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Tokyo',
            data: [49.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]               
        }, {
            name: 'New York',
            data: [83.6, 78.8, 98.5, 93.4, 106.0, 84.5, 105.0, 104.3, 91.2, 83.5, 106.6, 92.3]

        }, {
            name: 'London',
            data: [48.9, 38.8, 39.3, 41.4, 47.0, 48.3, 59.0, 59.6, 52.4, 65.2, 59.3, 51.2]

        }, {
            name: 'Berlin',
            data: [42.4, 33.2, 34.5, 39.7, 52.6, 75.5, 57.4, 60.4, 47.6, 39.1, 46.8, 51.1]

        }]
    });
});
```

Comment: cant work... I cant find the series of Tokyo,the click target is all charts , not series

Comment: thanks :) if you liked my answers please upvote and choose it as accepted :) cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

you have done it in a wrong way it should not be

```
data:{}
```

instead it should be

```
data:[]
```

here is a working example for you http://jsfiddle.net/ghRF9/1/.
here the click is defined only for the tokyo series

Hope this will help you

Comment: if you use series:[{data:[],events:{}},{data:[]}] it is specific to only that series